# Quiz functionality Get participant to land of the next que where he left

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I've written a quiz and I am using php. Now I am stuck here. I want the participant to land on the same question where he left, when he comes back to undertake the quiz again.

Straight to the point.
after looping through the results I have an array with question numbers which participant had already answered.

$array = (1,2,3,6,8,....and so on)

Now how can I get value number (3) from the array above. As I can see after three the sequence of taking the question breaks and he answered 8th question straight after answering number 3 question.

Now next time when he lands to do the quiz I want to take him to question number 4.

Hope that make sense.

Can any body please help me how to sort the array like that?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to record if the user completed the quiz and if not, get the set of the question numbers **not answered** and then get the minimum value. You'd want your array to look like this...

```
$questions = array(4, 5, 7, 9, ...);
```

And then you can just point the user to the minimum unanswered question number like so...

```
$resume = min($questions);
```

Granted you'd have to change your SQL call but this is basically just the inverse of whatever call you're using to get the answered questions anyway.

Comment: This min function will retun 4 what I want is 5

Comment: But didn't you say in your question that you'd want your quiz taker to go to question 4 because that's the first question he/she didn't answer?

Comment: But $array has to be like (1,2,3,6,8). Let's say array has the questions already answered. So from that point I can see the user has answered question 1,2,3 then 6 and 8. So logically the next question he need to answer is 4. I want them to jump to 4 by skipping 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand, why does the array have to contain only answered numbers? Why do you have a limitation on how you can work with your data and what data you can get?